# Memory management within loop

Tags: android

I am creating **table rows** within a TableLayout in a loop which goes till the size of an array. The size of my array is 120. In the loop, an object of another class is created.

```
for(int i=0; i<arrName.length; i++)
{
 MyClass *obj =new MyClass(this);
 /*

Some code  

*/
}
```

**Question**:

1) How do I release the object I have created?
2)Which default method is used to release objects created in an activity? (An example could be very useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java Memory Management is handle y the JVM.  You don't have to do anything for this is your code. You can follow this link for more details..http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: For what is onDestroy method used?

Comment: you should go through the Life Cycle methods of Android.

Answer (score 0):

You dont release objects in android (java), they are garbage collected when they are finished with. You should just make sure that you are not retaining any references to objects that you have finished using and the system will reclaim the memory when it needs to, or as part of a scheduled garbage collector pass.

Comment: For what is onDestroy method used?